# Selector query using search index

Tags: cloudant

Given the document:

```
{
  docId: "a1234",
  doc_type: "asset",
}
```

I have the following search index function in **_design/assets** with index name **search_asset**:

```
function(doc) {
   if (doc.doc_type !== 'asset') return;
   index('docId', doc.docId, { store: 'true', facet: 'true' });
}
```

However, when I try to search using the cloudant selector query:

```
{
  selector: { 
    docId: "a1234"
  },
  fields: ["docId"]      
}
```

It gives me this error: **Error running query. Reason: (no_usable_index) There is no index available for this selector.**

I also added the use_index option but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
{
  selector: { 
    docId: "a1234"
  },
  fields: ["docId"],
  opts: {
    use_index: ["_design/assets", "search_assets"]
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing Cloudant Query (aka Mango) and Cloudant Search (Lucene behind the scenes).

The `selector` syntax belong to the former, whereas the `index` function as described looks like a Search/Lucene index.

Cloudant Search -- both how to index and how to query is well documented [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.htm).

If you prefer the newer Cloudant Query, that's documented [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query).

There is some overlap, and Cloudant Query's text indexes are implemented on top of Cloudant Search, to confuse matters further.